# knex.js, would like to translate "and" condition in left join

Tags: knex.js

I have below query, I would like to represent this query in knex fromat. I have made it work by usng `raw` function but i am curious if it is possible with knex style.

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, s.userId
FROM title t LEFT JOIN
     subscribe s ON t.id  = s.titleId AND s.userId = 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
knex.select('*').from('title').leftJoin('subscribe', function() {
  this.on('subscribe.titleId ', '=', 'title.id')
      .andOn('subscribe.userId', '=', 1)
})
```

Answer (score 10):

```
knex('title as t')
  .select('t.id', 't.title', 's.userId')
  .leftJoin('subscribe as s', (builder) => {
    builder.on('t.id', 's.titleId').on('s.userId', knex.raw('?', [1]));
  })
```